# Output message with variable part to TeamCity build log from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, teamcity, write-host

I know that one can output messages to TeamCity build logs via specially decorated Write-Host:

```
write-host "##teamcity[message text='Prepearing backup folder']"
```

What if I need the message to contain a value of a variable as well.

I've tried the following:

```
$myFullMessage = "Perpearing backup folder at: " + $path
write-host "##teamcity[message text=$myFullMessage]"
```

But I get an error in an output stating that the message parameter provided should start with ' character.

Please let me know if I can output messages with variable value part in message body.

Comment: this: `"##teamcity[message text='$myFullMessage']"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is a string formatter. Otherwise you get in escape-character hell. Note how in Powershell that you must place two consecutive single-quote characters to put a literal one in the string.

```
$myFullMessage = "Perpearing backup folder at: " + $path
write-host $( '##teamcity[message text=''{0}'']' -f $myFullMessage )
```